# sed pattern from file and substitute with new pattern in another file using string variables

Tags: linux, bash, sed, bash-scripting

I have several files where I have the following patterns:

```
  t=        9.90000    2    2
  t=       10.00000    1    1
```

Now, the value of t (for example 100.00000) and also the value of (2    2) is changing.
I would like to rewrite this like the following:

```
t =   9.9 fs st=2
t =  10.0 fs st=1
```

Now, I am having a lot of difficulties to do that. What I am trying, after checking this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/719073/how-can-sed-get-patterns-from-a-file) is the following:

```
for i in {99..100};do 
  printf t="%*.5f\n" 16 $(($i))e-1 > 1.out
  x=$(grep -h -f 1.out output.xyz | cut -c 25-25)
  printf t="%*.1f fs st=$x\n" 6 $i > 2.out
  grep -h -f 1.out output.xyz > 3.out
  while read pattern; do 
    while read pattern2; do 
      sed -i 's/"${pattern}"/"${pattern2}"/' output.xyz
    done < 2.out
  done < 3.out
done
```

The problem here is that i create the file 3.out with the pattern to be substituted correctly, but when I read it into `pattern`, it takes away several blank spaces.

Instead of being `t=        9.90000    2    2`, it is `t= 9.90000 2 2`. I guess the main question here is how to send the correct amount of blank spaces to the variables `pattern` and `pattern2`.

I think I've been adding an excess of complexity, but in theory, should work...

I appreciate any help.

I paste below a sample of the file output.xyz if someone wants to try. Here I do the loop over 90 and 100, but eventually I will do from 0 to 200 spaced by 0.1.

```
  t=         9.90000    2    2
H      -0.036930458      0.778649616      1.520488735
C       0.027100908      0.020521063      0.815485702
H      -0.114216621     -1.115678468      1.549274509
C      -0.028047550      0.011852199     -0.815234987
H       0.117999971     -1.007943999     -1.373022932
H       0.044427848      0.883548719     -1.649093142
           6
  t=        10.00000    1    1
H      -0.038617790      0.777486447      1.520614461
C       0.027651801      0.020640376      0.817860457
H      -0.116497310     -1.116177809      1.544694024
C      -0.028248486      0.012015286     -0.816858295
H       0.118760018     -1.012065106     -1.371494658
H       0.043469061      0.885969826     -1.655114073
```

Thanks

Cayo Gonçalves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your results. When I try it 3.out looks correct, but the `sed` command doesn't work because the variables don't get substituted in single-quotes (the answer you copied from is just plain wrong, and there's a comment to that effect). Using just double-quotes, like `sed -i "s/${pattern}/${pattern2}/" output.xyz`, would work.

But as you said, it's overcomplicated. You're using an anti-pattern that's common among beginning scripters: finding things that need to be changed one-by-one, and then applying a change to the entire file (and hoping it only actually changes that one item). This is both inefficient (because it processes the entire file each time) and risky (because changes may get applied in unexpected ways in irrelevant places in the file).

You're actually doing something like this twice, first scanning the entire file for places where e.g. "...9.90000..." needs to be changed to "...9.9..." (so you scan the entire file for each number), then creating a replacement pattern for the line you found and applying *that* to the entire file (again, processing the entire file to change one line). If you do this for 0 to 200 in increments of .1, that means you're going to search the file 2,001 times, and edit it up to that many times -- that's 4,002 times through the entire file! And if the file actually has that many entries in it (and each one is followed by 6 lines of other data, as in your example)... 4,002 passes through 2001*7 lines is 56,056,014 total lines processed.

This will also fail weirdly if there are ever two lines in the file with the same t= number, because it tries to replace *all* of the matching lines with *all* of the reformatted versions (all but the first of which is garbled), without paying attention to which replacement goes with which original. It'll also behave weirdly if there are no matches for a number, although in that case it's not destructive.

(Note: it may be that there will never be more than one of the same t= number, in which case this approach will probably work. Probably. But it's still a bad way to do things.)

The better way to do things like this is to process the file *once*, using a method that handles all of the logic needed for the line it's processing right there on the spot, as it's processing it. You could do this in `sed` without too much trouble. If the numbers are always guaranteed to have zeroes after the first decimal place, this should work:

```
sed -Ei 's/^  t= +([ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9])0000 +([0-9]) +[0-9]$/  t= \1 fs st=\2/' output.xyz
```

Here, the `-E` option to `sed` tells it to use "extended" regular expression syntax, the `( )` in the pattern are "capture groups", which can be used in the replacement string as `\1` (the first one) `\2` (the second). In regex-speak, `[ 0-9]{3}` means "three characters that're all spaces and/or digits", and the various space-followed-by-`+` mean "one or more spaces" (you could replace these with just the right number of spaces if you wanted).

So basically, it matches the entire line (if it's in the format of the ones that need changing), captures the important sections, and replaces the line with a reformatted version with the captured bits of data in their places. Lines that aren't in that format won't be matched, so they'll be left unchanged.

(I'm also not sure the output format is quite right, since there are inconsistencies in what you have. Are there supposed to be spaces before the "t" in the output? Are there supposed to be spaces around the first "="? You may have to adjust the replacement string in my command.)

EDIT: to convert the `st` value, it's again best to add logic to do it in a single pass. You can do this in `sed` by using 4 patterns, one that matches "1" or "5" (`[15]` in regex notation) in the `st` column and produces "0" in the replacement, one that matches "2" or "6", etc. You can either use `-e` before each of the rules, or combine them into one long argument by separating them with `;`. Here's the `-e` version (broken into separate lines for readability):

```
sed -Ei \
    -e 's/^  t= +([ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9])0000 +([15]) +[0-9]$/  t= \1 fs st=0/' \
    -e 's/^  t= +([ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9])0000 +([26]) +[0-9]$/  t= \1 fs st=1/' \
    -e 's/^  t= +([ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9])0000 +([37]) +[0-9]$/  t= \1 fs st=2/' \
    -e 's/^  t= +([ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9])0000 +([48]) +[0-9]$/  t= \1 fs st=3/' \
    output.xyz
```

With this approach, you have to be careful that the edit rules don't chain (unless you want them to). That is, you don't want one rule to change the `st` value from "4" to "3", and then another rule to change that "3" to "2", etc. In this case, once a line has been converted it won't match the pattern anymore, so this can't happen (plus I put the rules in an order that'd prevent chaining anyway).

Another option is to switch to another program, like `awk`. `awk` is generally more powerful than `sed`, but also somewhat different in philosophy: it's more of a real programming language, and tends to think of lines of text as fields (in an input line, `$1` would be "t=", `$2` would be e.g. "9.90000", etc) although you can also work with the entire line (which `awk` calls `$0`). `awk` also knows math, so transforming the `st` value is just a matter of subtracting one and reducing modulo 4. One disadvantage is that most versions of `awk` don't support in-place editing (like `sed -i`), so you need to send output to a temp file and then use that to replace the input file.

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /  t= +[ 0-9]{3}[.][0-9]0000 +[1-8] +[0-9]$/) printf "  t=%6.1f fs st=%d\n", $2, ($3-1)%4; else print $0}' output.xyz >output.tmp &&
    mv output.tmp output.xyz
```

BTW, you do have a good backup of all of these files, right? Just in case something goes horribly wrong?

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you very much for your answer. You are absolutely correct, and did the right math too. I will also apply that to thousands of output.xyz files. Your suggestion worked very well. And just to finish answering your questions, yes, for the to-be-substituted pattern there is two blank spaces before t=, no space between t and =, and as for the replacement, as you wrote is super fine. Mine way was not working because when reading 3.out into variable `pattern2`, it was modifying it. It goes ok in the file, but not ok on the variable... Sed is indeed quite complex and powerful.

Comment: Could you please also help me with another question on this problem? So we now have st=X, where X can be 1-8. I would like to, whenever I have st equal to 1 or 5, to substitute it for 0, when it is 2 or 6 substitute for 1, when it is 3 or 7 substitute for 2 and when it is 4 or 8 substitute for 3. My initial thinking is to do 8 separated `sed` on the whole file, like `sed -i 's/st = 1/st = 0/g' output.xyz`, and this need to be done in a correct order. But I think, as you said, this is not the most efficient way. How would you do it?